# Grid typesetting for equations

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex, grid-typesetting

There were many discussions about grid typesetting in TeX. "Almost impossible"... I want to show that it is possible. I have found a way to make display math obey the grid. In contrast to packages like `grid` in my solution the math baseline is aligned to the other baselines, too. It works by absorbing tokes, as shown in this thread:
[Plain LuaTeX: Detecting if displaymath is ended by $$ or \Ustopdisplaymath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/plain-luatex-detecting-if-displaymath-is-ended-by-or-ustopdisplaymath)

MWE:

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\input 2columns.mac
\input luaotfload.sty
\catcode`\@=11

\newdimen\b@selineskip% the main baselineskip
\b@selineskip24.88\p@
\def\setstrut{\setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height.7\baselineskip
        depth .3\baselineskip width\z@}}% as in LaTeX

\font\twentyonerm="texgyrepagella-regular.otf:mode=node;script=latn;%
  language=DFLT;+tlig" at 20.74\p@
\font\twentyonemath="texgyrepagella-math.otf:mode=base;script=math" at 20.74\p@
\font\fourteenmath="texgyrepagella-math.otf:mode=base;script=math" at 14.4\p@
\font\tenmath="texgyrepagella-math.otf:mode=base;script=math" at 10\p@

\twentyonerm
\textfont\@ne\twentyonemath
\scriptfont\@ne\fourteenmath
\scriptscriptfont\@ne\tenmath
\normalbaselineskip\b@selineskip
\normallineskip\z@% very important!
\normalbaselines
\setstrut

\raggedbottom
\topskip.7\b@selineskip% important when \displaylines are split 
                       % over pages/columns and kills glue
\parskip\z@

% For the example equations
\Umathcode`!="5"1`!     \let\mathexclam=!%21
\Umathcode`.="0"1`.     \let\mathperiod=.%2E
\Umathcode`+="2"1`+     \let\mathplus=+
\Umathcode`-="2"1`−
\Umathcode`−="2"1`−
\Umathcode`/="0"1`/     \let\mathslash=/    \let\slash\mathslash%2F
\Umathcode`=="3"1`=     \let\equal==
\Umathcode`0="7"1`0
\Umathcode`1="7"1`1
\Umathcode`2="7"1`2
\Umathcode`3="7"1`3
\Umathcode`4="7"1`4
\Umathcode`6="7"1`6
\Umathcode`8="7"1`8
\Umathcode`π="7"1`π     \let\pi=π
\Umathcode`∑="1"1`∑     \let\sum=∑%2211
\Umathcode`∞="0"1`∞     \let\infty=∞%221E
\Umathcode`≈="3"1`≈     \let\approx=≈
\Umathcode`(="4"1`(     \Udelcode`(="1`(
\Umathcode`)="5"1`)     \Udelcode`)="1`)

\newdimen\@tempdima
\newdimen\@tempdimb
\newdimen\@tempdimc
\newdimen\@tempdimd

\abovedisplayskip\normalbaselineskip
\abovedisplayshortskip\normalbaselineskip
\belowdisplayskip\normalbaselineskip
\belowdisplayshortskip\normalbaselineskip

% make a box fit to the grid
\def\@fittogrid#1{\@tempdima\ht#1%
    \advance\@tempdima.1\b@selineskip%
    \divide\@tempdima\b@selineskip%
    \multiply\@tempdima\b@selineskip%
    \advance\@tempdima.7\b@selineskip%
    \global\ht#1\@tempdima%
    \@tempdima\dp#1%
    \advance\@tempdima.5\b@selineskip%
    \divide\@tempdima\b@selineskip%
    \multiply\@tempdima\b@selineskip%
    \advance\@tempdima.3\b@selineskip%
    \global\dp#1\@tempdima}

\newbox\gridb@x
\def\gridbox#1{\setbox\gridb@x\hbox{\Ustartmath#1\Ustopmath}%
    \@fittogrid\gridb@x%
    \box\gridb@x}

% Absorb tokens after $$
\newtoks\d@absorbed

\newdimen\@displaymathgap
\newdimen\@displaymathindent
\newif\if@eqno
\newdimen\@eqnnumheight
\newdimen\@eqnnumdepth
\newdimen\@eqnnumraise

\@displaymathindent40pt

\newif\ifh@lign
\h@lignfalse

\begingroup
\def~{\global\let\spacetoken= }~ %
\endgroup

\def\d@save@tokens#1{\global\d@absorbed\expandafter{\the\d@absorbed#1}}

\def\d@absorb{\global\d@absorbed={}\d@absorb@}
\def\d@absorb@{\futurelet\@next\d@absorb@check}
\def\d@absorb@check{%
    \ifx\@next\spacetoken
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@space
    \else\ifx\@next\bgroup
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@group
    \else\ifx\@next\displaylines% detect alignment displays!!!!! Not a nice solution! (A)
    \global\h@ligntrue
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@gobble
    \else\ifx\@next\eqalignno
    \global\h@ligntrue
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@gobble
    \else\ifx\@next\halign
    \global\h@ligntrue
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@gobble
    \else\ifx\@next\leqalignno
    \global\h@ligntrue
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@gobble
    \else\ifx\@next$%
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@finishI
    \else\ifx\@next\Ustopdisplaymath
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@finishII
    \else
    \let\@next=\d@absorb@gobble
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \@next}

\begingroup
\def~ {\d@save@tokens{ }\d@absorb@}
\global\let\d@absorb@space=~
\endgroup
\def\d@absorb@group#1{\d@save@tokens{{#1}}\d@absorb@}
\def\d@absorb@gobble#1{\d@save@tokens{#1}\d@absorb@}
\def\d@absorb@finishI$${\d@absorb@result}
\def\d@absorb@finishII\Ustopdisplaymath{\d@absorb@result}

\newbox\@eqbox
\newbox\@eqnobox

% Make an equation from the tokens
\def\d@absorb@result{\ifh@lign\the\d@absorbed\else
    \def\eqno{&\global\@eqnotrue}
    \def\leqno{&\global\@eqnofalse}
    \tabskip\z@skip
    \halign to \displaywidth{\setbox\@eqbox\hbox{\Ustartmath\displaystyle{##}\Ustopmath}
        \@fittogrid\@eqbox
        \global\@tempdimb\ht\@eqbox
        \global\@tempdimc\dp\@eqbox
        \global\@tempdimd\wd\@eqbox
        \hskip\@displaymathindent\box\@eqbox
        \tabskip0pt plus 1000pt minus 1000pt
        &\setbox\@eqnobox\hbox{\Ustartmath##\Ustopmath}
        \@fittogrid\@eqnobox
        \@displaymathgap\displaywidth% No collision between equation and tag
        \advance\@displaymathgap-\@displaymathindent
        \advance\@displaymathgap-\@tempdimd
        \advance\@displaymathgap-\wd\@eqnobox
        \@eqnnumraise\z@
        \llap{\hbox to \displaywidth{\if@eqno\hss
                \ifdim\@displaymathgap<0pt
                \@eqnnumraise-\@tempdimc
                \advance\@eqnnumraise-.7\normalbaselineskip\fi
                \else\ifdim\wd\@eqnobox>\@displaymathindent
                \@eqnnumraise\@tempdimb
                \advance\@eqnnumraise.3\normalbaselineskip\fi\fi
                \raise\@eqnnumraise\box\@eqnobox%
                \if@eqno\else\hss\fi}}%
        \tabskip\z@skip\cr
        \strut\cr% align to baselines at the top
        \noalign{\vskip-\baselineskip}
        \the\d@absorbed\cr}
    \fi$$}

\def\afterdisplay{\global\h@lignfalse\strut% align to baseline at the bottom (B)
    \vskip-\b@selineskip\vskip-\parskip\noindent\ignorespaces}
\jot=\baselineskip
\everydisplay{\aftergroup\afterdisplay\d@absorb}

%Redefine \displaylines to make it compatible to grid typesetting
\def\displaylines#1{\displ@y \tabskip\z@skip
    \halign{\hbox to\displaywidth{\hskip\@displaymathindent\@lign
            \gridbox{\displaystyle{##}}\hfil}\crcr
            \strut\cr
            \noalign{\vskip-\baselineskip}%
            #1\crcr}}

\noindent Let's try:
$$ ^x = ∑_0^∞ {x^n \over n!} \eqno (1) $$
This equation is about the natural exponential function.

With this equation you can proof Euler's identity:
$$ ^{π} + 1 = 0 \leqno (2) $$
with $ = (−1)^{1/2}$. Note that $(-8)^{1/3} = 1 + 3^{1/2}$, but not $−2$.
You must take the principal root!
$$ (2)^{1/2} = 1 +  $$
And:
$$ (8)^{1/2} = 2 + 2 $$

\vfill\eject

Some text.
$$ ^ ≈ 0.208 $$
Oh, this is a real number! I would have never expected that! I can't belive!
$^$ has no imaginary part!

Let us look at another equation:
$$
\displaylines{%
   ∑_{k=1}^n k = {n^2 + n \over 2} \cr
   ∑_{k=1}^n k = {n^2 + n \over 2} \cr}
$$

What about the derivative of the exponential function?:
$$ { \over x} ^x = ^x \eqno (3) $$

\bye
```

The MWE works very well but I have some questions:

- In the macro `\d@absorb@check` I added some lines to detect alignment displays like `\displaylines`. This is important as they have to be treated in another way. The line is marked with (A) in the MWE. This is ugly and inefficient as I have to add all alignment displays there. So if I define a new one I have to add it to. Is there a better way to detect if a macro contains an implicit `\halign`?
- In the macro `\afterdisplay` I reset to the baseline by a `\strut` with a negative `\vskip-...`. This also looks horrible. (Marked as (B) in the MWE.)
- Do you see some other possibilities to write all the code more efficient?

Thanks.

`2columns.mac` is from here: http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/misc/2columns.mac

[image]

Comment: “Do you see some other possibilities to write all the code more efficient?” Yes, use ConTeXt.

Comment: But also in ConTeXt, there must be some lines of code which do something similar. I like Plain TeX because of its simplicity and I wanted to show a solution. So many useres here complain about this missing feature in TeX, and now nobody seems to be interested in this thread. :(

Comment: I can't speak of others, but speaking of just myself: On a superficial reading at least, this looks like a demo (something cool you've accomplished) more than a question. This site works best with the format of focused questions and answers, so it's hard to place your question within that context: it looks like you already have something working, and are just asking "is there something better", but there's also a specific problem (not illustrated in the picture), and in either case I have the suspicion that if that's all the question was, you could ask a smaller question (or two small ones).

Comment: I might mention the new `tokcycle` package, https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle, which can examine and modify an input stream, token by token.  It is pretty straightforward to look for a particularly named macro, for example.  The examples file at the referenced site shows a number of applications.

Comment: While I did see over the years some requests about grid typesetting I wouldn't say that this are "so many users". Beside this: You may like plain for its simplicity but users want a more powerful format and they don't want to convert all their documents to plain only to gain grid typesetting (and if they are willing to convert then using context would make more sense anyway).  So the main problem is not to get something working but to integrate this in LaTeX and amsmath.

Comment: Well, as mentioned already by others: This is not a single question. If
I understand the meaning of MWE correctly then your solution does not
work for Computer Modern fonts. Others have published about the
problem, see http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf. Does
your solution improves on this result? I cannot run your code but my
solution uses \everydisplay to pack the display into a vbox that is
then adjusted in height and depth.

Comment: Does this solution work for **any** equation or is there a gotcha? I came here while searching for a solution to align equations in plain tex (though this itself is interesting, as I like grid typesetting in general). I wonder if there is a cleaner solution to grid-aligning equation by using luatex post_linebreak_filter, @HenriMenke could comment maybe? Like mark the "paragraph" that has equation, and then traverse the vertical list to remove glues & set spaces to adhere to multiple of baselines.

Comment: @reportaman No, there is no cleaner solution, also not with LuaTeX.  If you simply clobber all the vertical skips in the `post_linebreak_filter` you will end up with completely unpredictable vertical spacing.  The first step has to be that *absolutely all* of the vertical skips in LaTeX are consistently synchronized with the baselineskip.  Only then you can use the callback to enforce this and remove small inconsistencies.  Oh, and floats are not handled at all yet in this approach, because they can trigger the output routine at an arbitrary point during page building.

Comment: @Udo Wermuth: Sorry, but I think hat my solution ist better than the one in the link. There, they return to grid after each display math, but in my solution every baseline is right.

Comment: @reportaman: My solution works for all equations but you have to redefine the other alignment displays like `\eqalignno`, too. I did this only for `\displaylines` to keep the MWE short. When you define your own alignments you have to add them in `\d@absorb@check`.

Comment: @Henri Menke: I have written an output routine that fits the float boxes to the grid - without using Lua. ;)

Comment: I doubt that it is a good idea to have a grid for math mode. It might
work for simple formulas but I find that the vertical spacing is too
extreme; especially the displaylines in your right column have too
much space. And what does alignment means for the second sum compared
to the first column? The $k$ seems to be aligned but not the vertical
center of the formula.